# How to separate a dataframe in 2 different ones based on variable datatypes in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe with numeric variables and  categorical factors and i want to separate the dataframe into 2: one with the  numeric variables and one with the categorical factors.I am new to R and i am lost.I have tried the split function but i can't work it out.I tried using for loops for checking the variables with is.factor but nothing seems to work!Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there are only two types ('numeric' and 'factor'), we get the `class` of column types by looping through the dataset columns (`sapply(df1, class)`
) and use that to `split` the data.frame into a `list` of 'data.frame's.

```
lst <- split.default(df1, sapply(df1, class))
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
df1 <- data.frame(Col1 = LETTERS[1:5], Col2 = as.numeric(1:5), Col3= rnorm(5))
```